# ReactJs: Is it possible to render DOM to document by class name?

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJs and really like it. I wanted to ask if we can render virtual DOM to document by class name.

```
React.render(
    <CommentBox url="data/comments.json" pollInterval={2000} />,
    document.getElementById('class')
);
```

I tried to pass

> getElementByClassName('class')

as second argument to react's render method and it doesn't work. Does React only render DOM to nodes with ID's only or is there's a workaround to use nodes with classes too?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems you have used a wrong method.

Probably you should use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementByClassName`. And DO NOT forget `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like obj [*HTMLCollection*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), so picking the first element is necessary.

```
React.render(
  <CommentBox url="data/comments.json" pollInterval={2000} />,
  document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0]
);
```

For more infomation, check out the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

Comment: Why is the '[0]' necessary. Doesn't the 0 only apply to the first element with that classname? What if I have multiple elements with the same class name and I want to attach whats in my reactjs file to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

To answer Sam question in the answer above, as @xcatliu pointed out, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like list of HTML elements, so you could iterate through it using a for loop for example.

This way, same React component will be rendered as child to each HTML element with same class attribute.

Like below:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Hello</p>
    )
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("container").length; i++) {
  ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementsByClassName("container")[i]);
}
```

Comment: Note also that in the latest versions of React, the standard approach is to use `createRoot()`. 
See https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#rendering-an-element-into-the-dom

One should think about if creating multiple roots and rendering them separately in this way really makes sense though.