# Trying to render multiple reacts to multiple divs rather than an ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create multiple react comment boxes, I am using a package that was using #id rather than class, so would only render 1, not all of them. I have tried changing the `GetelemntbyID` to `getelemensbyclassname` but I am getting an error:

> Uncaught Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM
>   element.

**My code**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import CommentBox from './components/CommentBox.jsx';

window.Laravelista = window.Laravelista || {content_type: null, content_id: null, login_path: '/login'};

ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox content_type={Laravelista.content_type} content_id={Laravelista.content_id} login_path={Laravelista.login_path} />,
  document.getElementsByClassName('laravelista-comments')
);
```

I am trying to render them to the following div:

```
<div class="laravelista-comments"></div>
```

How can I acheive this?

Not a duplicate, this wants to apply to all, not just one with a classname,

Comment: can you share your commentBox.jsx. it would be better if you can make a jsfiddle demonstrating your problem.

Comment: @user3775217 http://pastebin.com/EzSdezia

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJs: Is it possible to render DOM to document by class name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556374/reactjs-is-it-possible-to-render-dom-to-document-by-class-name)

Comment: I'm sorry if my code looks stupid, I just started learning React.js. Maybe something like a list? Commentbox.js + Commentboxlist.js ?  [pastebin_code](http://pastebin.com/hthZGsvX)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an `HTMLCollection` of DOM elements rather a single one as React requires.

To render your app in the first one, only pass the first item of the collection by accessing the element at index zero:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox content_type={Laravelista.content_type} content_id={Laravelista.content_id} login_path={Laravelista.login_path} />,
    document.getElementsByClassName('laravelista-comments')[0]
);
```

Comment: As mentioned, I don't want the first but every one on the page.

Comment: @randommman In this case, you will have to loop through the `HTMLCollection` and call `ReactDOM.render()` once for each item. You cannot pass multiple DOM elements to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can not render a component by targeting a class, if you do, you will get this exception **Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.** To fix this just change `<div class="laravelista-comments"></div>` to `<div id="laravelista-comments"></div>` and finally

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox content_type={Laravelista.content_type} content_id={Laravelista.content_id} login_path={Laravelista.login_path} />,
  document.getElementById('laravelista-comments')
);
```

Hope this helps you?

Comment: You can only have one id per whole page, so it will only be applicable to one element and he has more than one element that he needs to target that's why he wanted to use class.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late, I've just get into the same problem. It seems a bit wierd but it works for me and I don't know why :)

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName('addToCart__button')){
    if (typeof NodeList.prototype.forEach === "undefined") {
        NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
    }
    if (typeof HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach === "undefined") {
        HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
    }
    var Nodes = []
    document.getElementsByClassName('addToCart__button').forEach(a => {
        Nodes.push(a);
    });
    Nodes.forEach(a => {
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                    <AddToCart sku={a.dataset.sku}/>
                </ConnectedRouter>
            </Provider>,
            a
        )
    });
}
```

Hope this would help someone!