# Can We render two different contents in two different divs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <span>Is React a JavaScript library for building user-interfaces?</span>,
  document.getElementById("question1")
)
ReactDOM.render(
  <form class="options">
    <input type="radio" value="Yes" />
    <input type="radio" value="No" />
  </form>,
  document.getElementsByClassName("options-main-container")
);
```

what's Wrong in this Code ???
I tried with different ways but not able to solve this
please anyone help me to solve this

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, try `document.getElementsByClassName("options-main-container")[0]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556374/reactjs-is-it-possible-to-render-dom-to-document-by-class-name

Comment: its better to use document.querySelector as it always returns one result and is universally supported

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly fine to call `ReactDOM.render` multiple times on the same page.

Here is the problem,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("options-main-container")
```

This returns `array` of elements with class name `options-main-container`. So you cannot directly render the element using this code. Either you need to iterate over the array or take just `1st` matching element like,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("options-main-container")[0] //This will get the 1st matching element
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelector` instead `getElementsByClassName`. Because `getElementsByClassName` returns nodelist Array and `querySelector` returns first matched element.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <span>Is React a JavaScript library for building user-interfaces?</span>,
  document.getElementById("question1")
)
ReactDOM.render(
  <form class="options">
    <input type="radio" value="Yes" />
    <input type="radio" value="No" />
  </form>,
  document.querySelector(".options-main-container")
);
```